# Solutions of $y^2=\binom{x}{0}+2\binom{x}{1}+4\binom{x}{2}+8\binom{x}{3}$ for positive integers $x$ and $y$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was interested in create and solve a Diophantine equation similar than was proposed in the section **D3** of [1]. I would like to know what theorems or 
techniques can be applied to prove or refute that the Diophantine equation of the title has a finite number of solutions, I don't have the intuition to know it. Our equation is given as $$y^2=2^0\binom{x}{0}+2^1\binom{x}{1}+2^2\binom{x}{2}+2^3\binom{x}{3},$$
thus using the definition of binomial coefficients we are interested in to solve this equation for positive integers $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq0$
$$3y^2=4x^3-6x^2+8x+3.$$

**Computational fact.** I got up to $10^4$ that the only solutions $(x,y)$ for positive integers $x,y\geq 0$ are $(x,y)=(0,1)$,$(2,3)$, $(62,557)$ and $(144,1985)$. For example our third solution is $$3\cdot 557^2=930747=4\cdot(62)^3-6\cdot (62)^2+8\cdot(62)+3.$$

> **Question.** Does the equation $$y^2=\binom{x}{0}+2\binom{x}{1}+4\binom{x}{2}+8\binom{x}{3}$$ have a finite number of solutions for positive integers $x,y\geq0$ ? If it is very difficult to solve, what work can be done? **Many thanks.**

### References:

[1] Richard K. Guy, *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, Problem Books in Mathematics, Unsolved Problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Springer-Verlag (1994).

Comment: Hi @GerryMyerson many thanks for your comments and attention on my posts, I read these and I appreciate all the comments. If this question result a good post I would like to dedicate this to you.

Comment: Using @ only alerts users who have already engaged with the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start with
$$ 3^2=4^3−6^2+8+3. $$
The change of variables $x=X/12$ and $y=Y/36$ gives the equation
$$ Y^2 = X^3 - 18X^2 + 288X + 1296. $$
Entering this into the LMFDB leads to the page
http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/315936/g/1 .
So your elliptic curve, after another change of variables to get rid of the $X^2$ term (replace $X$ by $X+6$) gives the curve
$$ Y^2 = X^3 + 180X +  2592. \quad(*) $$
According to the LMFDB, the curve $(*)$ has Mordell-Weil rank 2, generated by 
$ \left(-6, 36\right) $ and $ \left(18, 108\right) $. And in the form $(*)$, there are the following integral points, where only the point with positive $Y$ is listed:
$$ (-6, 36) ,\; (-3, 45) ,\; (18, 108) ,\; (24, 144) ,\; (28, 172) ,\; (738, 20052) ,\; (1722, 71460) ,\;(6189, 486891) .$$
This leads to the points
$$ (0, 1),\; (1/4, 5/4),\; (2, 3),\; (5/2, 4),\; (17/6, 43/9),\; (62, 557),\; (144, 1985),\; (2065/4, 54099/4) $$
on your original curve. giving the 4 integral points that you found.

Comment: Many thanks also for your great answer. I wondered that maybe an interesting problem can be, if it has a good mathematical content, to study the solutions of $P(x)={n\brace m}$, where $P\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and ${n\brace m}$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind. If do you like this problem feel free to study it as a present for you.

Answer (score 7):

The curve $y^2 = 1+\frac{8}{3} x - 2 x^2 + \frac{4}{3} x^3$ is elliptic.  Siegel's theorem says it has only finitely many integral points.

Comment: Many thanks I'am going to accept the other answer but your is also perfect. I provide you other equations if you want to study these. The first is $y^2=(x)_0+(x)_1+(x)_2+(x)_3$, where $(x)_n$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol. It is the equation $y^2=(x+2)^3-2(x+2)^2+1$, and the second is $y^2={x\brace 0}+{x\brace 1}+{x\brace 2}+{x\brace 3}$, where ${n\brace m}$ denotes Stirling numbers of second kind. Using the MathWolrd article *Stirling Number of the Second Kind* it should be the equation $2y^2=2^x+3^{x-1}+1$.

Comment: Few minutes ago I wondered about a different problem as a present for you: the relationship of Iannucci's equation ([1]) and the sequence *A277172* (see also the author of this sequence) from the OEIS. Exponentiating Iannucci's equation and using Fermat's little theorem one has that the solutions $n$ satisfy the congruence. I think that maybe you're interested in this because you've added comments in this article from OEIS. See Theorem 2 from Iannucci's article. **References:** [1] Iannucci, *On the Equation* $\sigma(n)=n+\phi(n)$,  Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 20 Article 17.6.2 (2017).